# Freeze on login Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, freeze

New installation of Ubuntu 20.04 with all updates installed.
It gets to logon screen you can select user and type in password.
Once you type in password it freezes with login screen vanishing and only mouse pointer visible but unmovable. This happen 50% of the time other times it works fine.

Comment: Stopped after update. Never happened again.